# Minted package on MacOSX

Tags: minted, macos, pygments

I am doing some troubleshooting on a Macbook Air (Linux user here) that has got an issue with running minted on MacOSX Mojave. I've been doing so successfully in Ubuntu, and never had any issues there. On Mojave, I installed pygmentize at usr/local/bin, and ran pdflatex via command line with the --shell-escape flag, but it is giving me a fatal error and no output. Is there anything I overlooked?

EDIT: This is a sample of the document I tried to compile - I have tried it on my own laptop, and it runs without any issues.

```latex
\usepackage{minted}
....
....
\begin{minted}
[
linenos
]
{python}
import math, random
import numpy as np
print "Hello World"
\end{minted}
```

The latex compile command I use on Linux is

`pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode SItest.tex`

Is there something macOS specific I need to change?

Comment: What is the error message you're given?

Comment: Fatal Error - 100 undefined \PYG control sequences (it lists them all in the log). Seems like it can't find the path to pygmentize, but I wouldn't know where else to put it

Comment: Could you supply a MWE so we can check the document syntax?

Comment: First you say pygmentize is in usr/local/bin, do you mean /usr/local/bin? Please check `which pygmentize` to make sure it's along the PATH. Also check `pygmentize -V` to see that it's actually executable. I'm having no problem on my system using macOS 10.14.5 (Mojave).

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It works fine on Debian, but not on OSX. Pygementize OSX: `Pygments version 2.4.2, (c) 2006-2019 by Georg Brandl.`, Linux: `Pygments version 2.2.0, (c) 2006-2017 by Georg Brandl.`

Comment: I just fixed it by deleting `_minted-main` directory.